# Return value from Future in Scala

Tags: scala, future

I have the following function :

```
  def getWayDepthFirst(maze: Maze, position: Position, way: List[Position]): List[List[Position]] = {
if (!canWalkOnCell(maze, position)) {
  Nil

} else {

  if (isExit(position, maze)) {
    List(position :: way)
  } else {

    val explorationArea: List[Position] = List(position.north, position.east, position.south, position.west) filter (x => !way.contains(x) && canWalkOnCell(maze, x))
    if (explorationArea.size > 1) {



    val possibleWays: Future[List[List[List[Position]]]] = Future.traverse(explorationArea)(notYetVisitedPosition => Future(getWayDepthFirst(maze, notYetVisitedPosition, position :: way)))

//        possibleWays.onSucces()

    } else {
      explorationArea.flatMap {
        (
          notYetVisitedPosition =>
            getWayDepthFirst(maze, notYetVisitedPosition, position :: way))
      }
    }
  }

}
```

It should find all the ways through a maze. If there are two or more possible ways that can be search then each of these should be handled in a future.

Now my problem is how to return the result of this. With the Future.traverse I end up with a `Future[List[List[List[Position]]]]` but what I need is a `List[List[Position]]`.

What is a possibility to return the correct value? And where do I do this? In the onSuccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zernike is correct in suggesting `future.map(_.flatten)`, but this will give you `Future[List[List[Position]]]` and not `List[List[Position]]`.

You are using `Future.traverse` to find possible ways in parallel, so you get a `Future[...]` as a result. You are suggesting to use `onSuccess` to return the `List[List[Position]]` from the `Future`, but with `onSuccess` you essentially register a callback function which will be executed when the `Future` ends successfully. Since the callback function will be executed independently of your `getWayDepthFirst` function, you can not return anything from inside this callback function.

The solution would be to change the result type of `getWayDepthFirst` to `Future[List[List[Position]]]`.

This would look like this :

```
def getWayDepthFirst(
  maze: Maze, position: Position, way: List[Position]
): Future[List[List[Position]]] = 
  if (! canWalkOnCell(maze, position)) {
    Future.successful(Nil)
  } else if (isExit(position, maze)) {
    Future.successful(List(position :: way))
  } else {
    val positions = List(position.north, position.east, position.south, position.west)
    val explorationArea = positions filter (x => 
      !way.contains(x) && canWalkOnCell(maze, x)
    )
    Future.traverse(explorationArea)( notYetVisitedPosition => 
      getWayDepthFirst(maze, notYetVisitedPosition, position :: way)
    ).map(_.flatten)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, so I would handle the onSuccess where I am calling this method the first time I guess. I still get an error with this though.

`type mismatch; found : scala.concurrent.Future[List[List[Position]]] required: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Position]]` on this line `getWayDepthFirst(maze, notYetVisitedPosition, position :: way))
    ).map(_.flatten)`

Comment: Seems that there was just on ) too much infront of map(_.flatten)

Comment: You are correct,  I have removed the parenthesis from the code. You can find more information on working with `Future` on the [Scala website](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

Comment: You can use scalaz's `traverseM` to replace the `.traverse(...).map(_.flatten)`.